# "Since he came from extreme poverty, a stable 9 to 5 job was the the biggest ambition that he ever had."

Tags: sentence-construction

So I was writing an article, for practice. But somehow, I feel the below phrase does not sound right.

> Since he came from extreme poverty, a stable 9 to 5 job was the the biggest ambition that he ever had.

I feel "biggest ambition" ambition is not the right way of defining, to what extent is someone's "ambition".

Comment: We use metaphoric ***highest** ambition* for such contexts. We also talk about ***aiming high*** or ***setting one's sights high*** to mean ***highly / very ambitious***.

Comment: *greatest ambition* is worth considering, and it should probably be *he has ever had* unless the context calls for Simple Past somehow, but there's nothing inherently wrong with the sentence (other than the repeated *the*, but I guess that's just a typo).

Comment: Or the simpler *a stable 9 to 5 job was his highest ambition.*

Comment: See [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+biggest+ambition%2Chis+highest+ambition%2Chis+greatest+ambition&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20biggest%20ambition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20highest%20ambition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20greatest%20ambition%3B%2Cc0), showing that ***his biggest ambition*** effectively "flatlines" against the more common ***his highest ambition***. But *syntactically*, both are fine.